# Python3 can't find scipy, numpy, ipython

Tags: python-3.x

I have CentOS6 and didn't see any "python3" listed by `yum search python` so downloaded the python3 .tgz and extracted it to `/usr`. I ran the install scripts and the interpreter works. Then I installed scipy, numpy, ipython with `yum`. I start the python3 interpreter again, yet it appears it cannot find the scipy and numpy libraries. For example, `import numpy` will err in the interpreter.

What must be done to make python3 to find these libraries?

Comment: Uh, install them under Python 3.

Comment: To extent Igancio's comment: each Python version (2.6, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3 etc) will have its own version of libraries, such as numpy and scipy. The default numpy and scipy packages you installed are for Python 2, so these will be installed somewhere slightly different, and Python 3 won't find them. Hence, you'll have to install them yourself as well (using pip3 may help here).

Comment: Also, it's a *very bad* idea to install your Python 3 interpreter under `/usr`. Unless you did a `make altinstall`, you'll now have `/usr/bin/python` being Python 3; this may break some system scripts that except Python 2 being there. Use `/usr/local` for self-installed stuff.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams there is no apparent way to `yum install`  "under python 3", so I'm not clear on what you mean. 

@Evert How would I install numpy, scipi propertly, assuming my Python3 install diredtory is `/usr/local/python3`?

Comment: @T.Webster: install [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/) for Pyhton 3; from there, I think you're safe to just run `pip3 install numpy` etc. If that doesn't work, you'll have to do manual installations; see the corresponding webpages for source downloads and installation instructions.